# How to scroll ListView to a particular id and set that item as checked?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a ListView mapped to a SQLCursorAdapter. By default, I always want to have the view corresponding to a particular id checked, and have the ListView scrolled so as to make that particular item visible. How do I achieve that?

Note: The number of items can be a few hundreds, and item I want to have checked can be anywhere in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the method,

```
listView.setSelection(position)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

From [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29), that sounds like it should do what you're after.

As for setting the item to checked, simply use something like the following (I'm assuming it's a checkbox you have as a variable):

```
checkbox.setChecked(true);
```